# How to check if Angular application running in Production or Development mode

Tags: angular, production

This seems an easy one, but I couldn't find any solution.

So, how do I check if my app is running in production mode or dev mode?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

You can use this function **[isDevMode](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/isDevMode-function.html)**

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

...
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log(isDevMode());
  }
}
```

**One note**: **be carefull** with this function

```
if(isDevMode()) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

You will get

> Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L58

## Other options

**environment variable**

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  //
}
```

**injected by webpack process.env.NODE_ENV variable**

```
declare let process: any;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if (env  === 'production') {
  //
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error you mentioned. "Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup". Could you please help me in getting this resolved? @yurzui

Comment: @Gowtham You have to enable it before calling `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`

Comment: That is exactly how I'm calling it. Still I'm getting this error every time I try running the app in production mode @yurzui. Any help resolving this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Gowtham Do you have any example to reproduce it?

Comment: This is my "main.ts" import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

is it possible for you to resolve this in chatroom? Is this what you wanted? @yurzui

Comment: It works perfectly! I could separate between prod and dev projects in firebase with that method!

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode "After called once, the value is locked and won't change any more." The answer should include the doc and this warning!

Comment: Is there something similar for AngularJS?

Comment: To improve readability in the console log, prepend some message to the boolean result that is getting logged. Else you only see true or false in the console, which might come from anything. Sample:
`console.log("Angular in Development mode: " + isDevMode());`

Answer (score 63):

Per the Angular Deployment guide at https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-production-mode:

> Building for production (or appending the --environment=prod flag)
>   enables *production mode* Look at the CLI-generated `main.ts` to see how
>   this works.

`main.ts` has the following:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

So check `environment.production` to see if you are in production.

Most likely you do NOT want to call `isDevMode()`.  Per the Angular API documentation at https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode:

> After called once, the value is locked and won't change any more...
>   By default, this is true, unless a user calls enableProdMode before calling this.

I've found that calling `isDevMode()` from an `ng build --prod` build always returns true and always locks you into running in dev mode.  Instead, check `environment.production` to see if you are in production.  Then you will stay in production mode.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (Proper doc linking and explanations.)

Comment: The fact that the value won't change doesn't imply that you don't want to call it. You shouldn't be switching from dev mode to prod mode and back while your application is running. So when you're trying to determine whether you should enable production mode, the environment variable is the right way to go, but if you have a service that needs to behave a little differently when in dev mode, `isDevMode()` is a perfectly fine way to accomplish that.

Comment: I don't think this is still valid. New Angular versions don't even generate an env automatically, and if you generate it through schematics it won't have a production property

Answer (score 10):

Simply check the production variable present in the environment file, it will be true for production mode and false for development.

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  // for production
} else {
  // for development
}
```

Answer (score 6):

#### it depends on what you are asking...

If you want to know the `mode` of Angular, as @yurzui said, you need to call `{ isDevMode } from @angular/core` but it can return `false` only if you call `enableProdMode` before it.

If you want to know the **build environment**, in other words, if your app is running minified or not, you need to set a build variable in your build system... Using `Webpack`, for example, you should have a look at `definePlugin`.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  ENV_PRODUCTION: !!process.env.NODE_ENV
});
```

Comment: I was actually looking for both. I am using webpack (through the angular-cli), where do I add your lines of code? How do I have access to that variable in my typescript files? I would be great if you could update your answer with that

Comment: Following this http://ngcli.github.io/#getting-started-project-structure you should edit the webpack.config.js then follow the link in my answer...

Comment: The link in your post is outdated, heres the correct one for the [Define Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Answer (score 4):

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module'


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
enableProdMode();
```

This was my code, so I got the same error. I just interchanged line 3 and 4. Then the issue is **fixed**. So before bootstrapping module we should enable --prod mode.

The correct one can be put in this way,

```
enableProdMode()
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Interestingly, my new Angular 9 app seems to have put these lines (in this order!) into my "main.ts" file already.  It seems to be the default now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful that you check the return value of the `isDevMode()` function.

My setup was failing because i was checking for existence: `if (isDevMode)` was always `true`, even in production because i declared it with `import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';`.

`if (isDevMode())` returned `false` correctly.

Comment: try to build you app with `ng build --prod=true` via angular cli

Comment: `if ( isDevMode )` only checks if the identifier **isDevMode** is defined, not null, and not empty nor zero. As the identifier was defined in `@angular/core` that **if()** will always return **true**.
Now, `if( isDevMode() )` will actually call the function and it will return if it's development environment or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare let process: any;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

export const environment = {  
  apiURL: (env  === 'production') 
    ? 'https://example.com/api'
    : 'http://localhost:8080/api'
};
```