# process.env.IONIC_ENV is returning dev

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

`process.env.IONIC_ENV` is returning `dev` always.

Here is the script I've used.
`ionic serve --prod`

But `process.env.IONIC_ENV` is returning `dev` instead of `prod`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-2-app-is-running-in-production-or-dev)

Comment: Thanks @PhilipBrack but I'm more looking for ionic cli env solution for this since I need to build the ios and android app via cli, as well.

Comment: Hi @PatrickBlind. I am faced with the same dilemma.  Did you ever find a solution?  I am using ionic-angular 3.9.2.  See my posting at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917641/ionic-angular-3-9-2-ignores-prod-and-only-does-dev-builds