# Ionic-angular 3.9.2 ignores '--prod' and only does '--dev' builds

Tags: ionic3

I've been back and forth and spend tons of hours looking through Stackoverflow and the web at large, and I still have not been able to find an workable answer to this delimma.

For our application, as shown from the below excerpts from package.json, we are using the following excerpts:

`"ionic-angular": "^3.9.2"`

`"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9"`

```
  "config": {
    "ionic_generate_source_map": "false",
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js",
    "ionic_copy": "./copy-custom.js"
  }
```

I have a (seemingly correct) `webpack.config.js` file (below)
[image]

When I do a build, it appears as if everything is going to the --prod builds, but it is sill pulling from my dev settings (as verified be my testers).  I even set up an environment variable on our mobile app to show the env settings, and they are showing production.

[image]

Yet, .... the dev(test) data that is entered in the `environment.ts` file is overriding everything, and constantly being used as the env values.  How is this possible?  I have looked at every link I can find, but no luck.  I cannot upgrade to ionic 4 at the moment as there will be breaking changes; our current code base is heavily linked to ionic 3.

Any advice?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082565/process-env-ionic-env-is-returning-dev

Comment: let me guess.. you are using windows?;) i had same problem had to use cross-env library to work around this. if interested i can try posting my solution at that time

Comment: No. I am a sole Mac user. I’d still be interested in your solution .