# Is it possible to write a piece of code that will get omitted in prod version

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to somehow "mark" a piece of code so it will be included in "dev" mode but will be omitted in "prod".

I know angular has:

```
if (isDevMode()) {...}
```

But can I avoid the code checking whether it is dev mode as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-application-running-in-production-or-development-mode this may help you

Comment: this would be a head start if you want to build something on your own. https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/disabling-javascript-console-in-production-enviroments-and-internet-explorer/

Comment: If you look at `configurations.production.fileReplacements`, you'll see that `src/environments/environment.ts` is replaced with `src/environments/environment.prod.ts`. I'm pretty sure you can create a `boolean` property in here and then import the environments in your code to check if it's in `prod` mode, and then do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is using the environment.ts for that.

In your environment.dev.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    doSomething() {
       // Do your dev stuff here
    }
}
```

In your environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    doSomething() {
        // Leave empty
    }
}
```

And in your component/service/wherever call it from environment. Since environment will be replaced, the dev code will only be included in your dev bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a build tool like webpack and have it include files based on an alias combined with the `NODE_ENV`. `NODE_ENV` is `development` in dev mode and `production` in prod.

The easiest way would be in your webpack.dev.config have the alias load the dev file, and in the webpack.prod.config load the production file.

`// dev
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Something: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev/foo/')
    }
  }
};`


`// prod
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Something: path.resolve(__dirname, 'prod/foo/')
    }
  }
};`

If you wanted to use one config file you could just use a ternary in the config.

Answer (score 0):

Just import your environement file in your component:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

and in your script do :

```
if (!environment.production) {
  .....
}
```

Comment: your solution still adds an extra check in production. just like if (isDevMode()) {...}