# Make Angular ignore errors in template

Tags: angular

I am using [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to create a list of items. In production, my app had a bug and stopped the list at an item that caused an exception during the execution of my template.

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos">
    <p>{{foo.this.attribute.doesnt.exist}}</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to enable a production mode, in which Angular simply skips this list entry? I prefer to have a list not being present in the list rather than breaking it mid-way and destroying the layout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-application-running-in-production-or-development-mode

Comment: What exceptions are you referring to? If they're all just missing attribute exceptions then Oussail's answer is probably your best bet.

Comment: do not put your business in your HTML code! then you will be just worrying about some basic errors like undefined objects that could handle by the "?" operator as @Oussail said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can add the sign **?** to the properties which you don't know if they are defined or not.

**Example :**

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos">
    <p>{{foo?.this?.attribute?.doesnt?.exist}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful, but `foo?.this?.attribute?.doesnt?.exist` was just an example. Sometimes there is a variety of possible other errors. Is there another way to make this work for all types of exceptions?