# How to check which environment is currently used

Tags: javascript, angular

When running my project locally with `ng serve`, I want to execute some different code blocks than when I run the prject on my server (we have a DEV, STAGING and a PROD environment on the server.)
So I need to check if I'm currently running on

- LOCAL,
- or on DEV, STAGING, PROD.

Here [How to check if Angular application running in Production or Development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-application-running-in-production-or-development-mode) are answers to how to check, if the project is running in DEV or PROD Mode (e.g. with `isDevMode`). So it would only help if I needed to check if I'm running on

- LOCAL, DEV, STAGING,
- or on PROD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a `name` attribute in my `environemt.ts` files and then checking for this attribute in the code:

```
if (environment.name === 'LOCAL') {
  console.log('%c LOCAL MODE', 'color: orange;')
} else {
  ... not local
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Node.js, you can may use the environment-variables.
In your case its:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "development" )
```

[further examples](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs)