# How do I detect the running configuration in Angular 16?

Tags: angular, environment

The question may seem trivial but I didn't find any answer around. Many people reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-application-running-in-production-or-development-mode), which I suppose is not valid anymore.

The problem is the following: as Angular 16 (I didn't check previous versions), the command `ng new project` won't generate the environment configuration anymore, which won't be needed for running the application.

We can use `ng generate environments` to generate the environments scaffolding, but it will look different than before: it will be a bunch of plain typescript files that will take the place of the `envinroment.ts` file. No `production` property is available.

In the `angular.json` some configurations are available, and many more can be added. The default property looks like this:

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

But we can add other configurations like `test`, `staging`, and so on. Once added a configuration we can run the project using a configuration with:

```
ng build --configuration=development
```

This is exactly the value I'm trying to detect (nothing like `isDevMode()`), I just want to know if the configuration `development`, `production`, `staging` etc was used to run the application.

How can I detect this value?

Comment: How about just putting an environment: 'dev' | 'prod' | 'etc' setting in the environment.dev|prod|etc config file?

Comment: @Mike yes this is my temporary solution. It looks a bit ugly because I've to do `environment.environment === 'dev'`, it's not type-safe, and it's arbitrary, but it works. I'm looking for a more solid and canonical solution

Comment: You could make it type safe by implementing an interface and on the interface use a union of 'dev' | 'prod' | 'etc' or make your own type export type EnvironmentName = 'dev' | 'prod' | 'etc' and then export interface Environment { name: EnvironmentName, ...other settings... }

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Getting an answer and then saying you don't like it because it looks ugly and doesn't conform to requirements you didn't specify in your question makes it difficult to give you a definitive answer.  Edit your question to include what you *do* want.

Comment: Like @Mike said, that's generally what I do for my environments since I have some items that I only want to show/run in the dev or stage environments (displaying a button for direct access to a user feedback form for testers, etc). Works perfectly well and is a great way to control different environments within the application.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend anyone, but it really feels like a hack. What I want is something that allows me to access the configuration that I set in the command line, without adding any manual information to each configuration

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do...

```
// **************************
// environment.interface.ts
// **************************
export type EnvironmentName = 'dev'|'prod'|'test'|'etc';

export interface Environment {
  name: EnvironmentName; // or w/o custom type just use 'dev'|'prod'|'test'|'etc'
}

// **************************
// environment.development.ts
// **************************
import {Environment} from 'environment.interface.ts';

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: false,
  name: 'dev'
};

// **************************
// environment.production.ts
// **************************
import {Environment} from 'environment.interface.ts';

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: true,
  name: 'prod'
};

// **************************
// environment.test.ts
// **************************
import {Environment} from 'environment.interface.ts';

export const environment: Environment = {
  production: false,
  name: 'testing' // <- Ex: This won't compile, value isn't 'dev'|'prod'|'test'|'etc'
};
```

Then use the interface when you inject environment for type safe interaction:

```
import {Environment} from 'environment.interface.ts';

/* snip */
constructor(@Inject('environment') private environment: Environment) {}
/* snip */
```

I usually keep that interface in an external angular library, but it doesn't need to be...hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid the manual configuration of each environment since it feels like duplicating the config in the `angular.json`, but I think I'll use this pattern